# Misbehaving assertRaises

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertraises

I have class and method as below:

```
class Calculator(object):

    def add(self, x, y):
        try:
            if not isinstance(x, int) or not isinstance(y, int):
                raise TypeError
        except TypeError:
            print "Parametr has wrong type"
        else:
            return x + y
```

I want to write a unit test that checks if the given parameters are correct type. When you type will be angry, throw a TypeError.

```
import unittest
from Calculator import Calculator

class TDD_in_python_example(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add_correct(self):
        calc = Calculator()
        result = calc.add(2, 3)
        self.assertEqual(5, result)

    def test_when_type_is_ok(self):
        calc = Calculator()
        result = calc.add(2, 3)
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, result, 2, 3)

    def test_when_type_of_parameter_is_wrong(self):
        calc = Calculator()
        result = calc.add(2, 3)
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, result, "two", "three")

    def test_when_one_type_of_parameter_is_wrong(self):
        calc = Calculator()
        result = calc.add(2, 3)
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, result, 2, "three")

    def test_when_two_type_of_parameter_is_wrong(self):
        calc = Calculator()
        result = calc.add(2, 3)
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, result, 'two', 3)
```

When given the correct type of test parameters should show the error, and it is not. Why?
Please for help/some hint

Comment: I see a few problems - [a] you are catching the exception, and then printing an error - you need to raise it [b] you are passing the result of the function to assertRaises, you need to pass the method itself: `asserRaises(Exception, method_name, arg1, arg2)`

Comment: Additionally to the above comment.  If you do not have the statement at the end to run this class ( if __name__ == "__main__":   unittest.main()).  The class is only loaded and not actually executed.     I am assuming that you posted all of the code you have.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Thank you, I think now is good. Test is Failure and AssertionError: TypeError not raised